# Both Monitors Randomly Turning Off Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, temperature, external-monitor

Both my internal and external monitors will randomly shut off for no reason, but they turn back on when I move my mouse around. I have checked my settings and my auto-suspend and other options are either disabled, or within a 1 hour period instead of a 20 second period. I don't know if this might be related, but I can't use Performance Mode due to the system claiming the temperature is high, but from what I found, that's a separate bug entirely.

PC Specs:

GTX 1050 4GB

Intel Core i5-8300h

DDR4 8GB RAM 2667 MT/S

Comment: It would be good if you include the pc specs.

Comment: @MaheswarKARAKKATTUKISHORKUM I have added the PC Specs

Comment: and you've checked `Settings` under the `Power` tab?

Comment: Is your external monitor connected to a power extender, or plugged in the wall?

Comment: @MaheswarKARAKKATTUKISHORKUM My external monitor is connected to the wall.

Comment: @Bovine I checked there multiple times to see if I could find new information, I haven't found anything I haven't already listed.

Comment: what do you get for `xset q | grep -i dpms`?

Comment: @Bovine
`DPMS (Energy Star):
  DPMS is Enabled`

Comment: you can try `xset s off && xset -dpms` to disable it, but I am pretty sure it will reset the next time you reboot.

Comment: @Bovine I'll try that after I restart, I was set to a different GPU than I normally use so I wanted to switch to that.

Comment: First, [make sure all your sensors are properly detected](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto).

Answer (score 1):

If the monitors both turn off at once and come back on with keyboard or mouse movement, this is probably not random, but the idle time screen saver kicking in, which is separate from the rest of the power saving settings and not related to auto suspend.

At the low level, this is controlled by the DPMS settings in X11 which can be viewed with `xset -q` and the timings set with `xset dpms` or it can be disabled entirely with `xset -dpms`.

In ubuntu, using gnome, in the power menu, this is labeled as `blank screen` after ...minutes.

However, the settings in the power menu may not be relevant, as multiple applications seem to mess with the DPMS settings and change them.  (For example, the built in screen lock, games, video players, gnome-shell apps like caffeine, etc., and of course xset)

You may be able to use something like caffeine to configure DPMS to be disabled when certain apps run.

If you want to change the settings with xset, look at the DPMS section of the output of `xset -q` : (excerpt)

```
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 300    Suspend: 400    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

- This means after 300 seconds, it will tell your screen to enter the first level power saving, after 400 seconds, it will enter second level power saving, and after 600 seconds, it will shut the monitor off completely.  This was more meaningful in the days of tube monitors, where first level could be reversed instantly, and deeper levels took longer.  Now probably all three levels are the same on LCD screens.
- You can disable it with `xset -DPMS` and then it should say "DPMS Disabled"
- You can change the timings (or set them to the above) with `xset DPMS 300 400 600`
- You can turn the monitor off instantly with `xset dpms force off`

Comment: What am I looking for with the `xset -q` command?

Comment: Added to answer.